# What are utility classes in CSS? Beginner CSS developer

Tags: css

There are these utility classes. I'm a beginner in CSS, and I want to organise my CSS in a better way.

```
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no formal definition of 'utility class'.

However, a common use of the phrase applies to simple, often single setting, classes with some semantics attached to the class name.

So in your examples perhaps a more 'utility' view would be to recognise that there may be several padding settings, for example and set the nomenclature accordingly.

```
.shadow-10-red {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
.padding-10 {
  padding: 10px;
}
.radius-10 {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.card-red {
  background-color: red;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

However, these are utilities, very basic, and so are used rather differently from a normal class that sets several properties at once.

In the change of padding shown in the discussion on [Charles Lavalard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053172/what-are-utility-classes-in-css-beginner-css-developer/69053212#69053212), I worry that the p-1 class, which initially appears to have a link to the semantics - viz 1em, then gets changed to mean 1.5em. That isn't my understanding of a utility class.

But then perhaps it's all getting a bit subjective because utility classes don't have a standard definition. And perhaps the p-1, etc. in that example was not intended to have anything to do with the property values, but it was saying 'the first of the padding choices' which would be logical.

Comment: `.padding-10 {
  padding:10px;
}
.radius-10 {
  border-radius:10px;
}` but i dont want to fix these values it can be 10px to 15px later.

Comment: Then I would just use padding without the -10 added as you have done initially otherwise I find it quite hard to understand the code, but it's all a matter of choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use more specific names for your class, so if you want a specific `padding` for example, you can have multiple options:

```css
.block {
  color: white;
  background-color: teal;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p-1 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.p-2 {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: 3rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .p-1 {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }
  .p-2 {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
  .p-3 {
    padding: 3.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block p-1">Padding 1</div>
<div class="block p-2">Padding 2</div>
<div class="block p-3">Padding 3</div>
```

You can take a look at [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/), for example.

Comment: thanks but what if we want to change `p-1` to `1.5rem` in responsive ?

Comment: For this you can add media queries,
I edited the answer to show you

Comment: Utility classes mainly have one property

Comment: then what we call those classes have multiple properties ?

Comment: Read this article, it can help you https://designsystem.digital.gov/utilities/